# Why select list does not show selected option

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When user selects value from dropdown list, the selected value is not shown after page reload. Only "All" is shown as selected. If I give an attribute in the  as :

```
<option value="@trChannel.TrCode" selected = "@trChannel.TradeChanelDisplayText">@trChannel.TradeChanelDisplayText</option>
```

The value All is never shown as selected and when page is loaded the last option from list is shown. How can I fix this?

```
<section>
    <table id="filters">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:180px">
                <span class="snsSmallTextBold">Filter by Trade Channel: </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="TradeChannelCode" style="width:200px" id="selectedTradeChannel">
                    <option value="" id="all">All</option>
                    @foreach (var trChannel in Model.FilterableTrChannels)
                    {
                        <option value="@trChannel.TrCode">@trChannel.TradeChanelDisplayText</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <button id="addTrChannel" style="background-color:white">Add Trade Channel</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:410px"></td>

            <td style="width:210px; float:right">
                <span class="snsSmallTextBold">Filter by Subtrade Channel: </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="SubtradeChannelCode" style="width:200px" id="selectedSubtradeChannel">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    @foreach (var subtrChannel in Model.FilterableSubTrChannels)
                    {
                        <option value="@subtrChannel.SubTrCode">@subtrChannel.SubtradeChanelDisplayText</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="addSubtrchannel" style="background-color:white">Add Subtrade channel</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#filters select").change(function () {
            load();
        });
    });

    function load() {
        var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        url = url + '?TradeChannelCode=' + $("#selectedTradeChannel").val() + '&SubtradeChannelCode=' + $("#selectedSubtradeChannel").val();
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A selected property can only be "selected". `<option selected="selected"`: Basic htlml rules here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: your answer does not fix my problem.  When I use the selected option I end up either with :
1. option All to be always shown as selected even though another selection is maintained and the data is sorted as per that selection
2. option All is never shown as selected even when it is selected and page is reloaded and data is organized as All is selected but dropdown shows the last created option from the foreach ....

Comment: You haven't got anything in the code to tell the dropdown what is selected on the reload.